# Error when restoring encrypted database

Tags: sql, tde

I use the following to create certificate for database encryption.

```
use master
--create certificate
CREATE CERTIFICATE Cert4TDE WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for TDE';
GO
--back up certificate
BACKUP CERTIFICATE Cert4TDE TO FILE = 'E:\asd\Cert4TDE.crt'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY ( FILE = 'E:\asd\privateKeyOfCert4TDE.pvk' , 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssword2' );
GO
Use  [Test5]
GO
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION   KEY
     WITH ALGORITHM   =  AES_256 --Supported encryption algorithms are AES with 128-bit,   192‑bit, or 256‑bit keys or 3 Key Triple DES
     ENCRYPTION BY   SERVER CERTIFICATE   Cert4TDE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test5]
SET ENCRYPTION ON;
```

GO

After backuping T5 database and remove the certificate from SQL, I try importing certificate from file

```
create certificate Cert4TDE
      from file = 'E:\asd\Cert4TDE.crt'
      with private key 
        (file = 'E:\asd\privateKeyOfCert4TDE.pvk', 
         encryption by password = 'P@ssword2',
         decryption by password = 'P@ssword2')
```

I expect that after importing the certificate, I can restore Test5 database, but it throws error : ***the certificate has a private key that is protected by a user defined password*** . what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you tag the dbms product used you will maybe get more attention.

Comment: I totally could not figure out what you mean, jarlh?